# Making git ignore all of a directory tree except some files

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to get git to ignore the entire `packages` directory except for `.targets` files inside it, wherever they may be.  I'm trying this in `.gitignore` but git still ignores the entire `packages` dir despite the presence of `.targets` files:

```
/packages/*
!/packages/**/*.targets
```

I've also tried following advice from another SO question and un-blacklisting directories first but it still didn't work (this time, it just included all of the packages dir again):

```
/packages/*
!/packages/**/
!/packages/**/*.targets
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: No, even following advice there it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out - the key is understanding that Git can ignore both directories and files, but if it ignores a directory it won't then search that directory's sub-structure for the remainder of the `.gitignore`.

So first you ignore everything in the `/packages` contents, then you *only* whitelist the directories (which will still add nothing because an empty directory in Git, or one with all its files ignored, doesn't get added), then you whitelist the `.targets` files which will now work because the directories have been whitelisted, so Git will look in their sub-structure to find the files to whitelist:

```
# Ignore the NuGet packages folder contents in the root of the repository...
/packages/**/*
# (whitelist directories to allow file exclusions later)
!/packages/**/
# ...except target files which may be required for msbuild.
!/packages/**/*.targets
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this file:

```
/packages/**/*
!/packages/**/
!/packages/**/*.targets
```

**Explanation**

When you ignore **a folder**, git won't check that folder at all, so you can't exclude any file inside it from ignorance later.

Since you want to keep some specific files tracked, instead of ignoring a folder itself, you should ignore **all files** inside the folder first, then exclude specific files you want to track.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Well, just updated.